# Allocatable character variables in Fortran

Tags: fortran, character, trim

My code (stripped down to what I think is relevant for this question) is

```
PROGRAM test

IMPLICIT NONE

CHARACTER(len=37) input
CHARACTER(len=:), allocatable :: input_trim


WRITE(*,*) 'Filename?'
READ(*,*) input
ALLOCATE(character(len=LEN(TRIM(input))) :: input_trim)
input_trim=trim(input)

.
.
.

END PROGRAM test
```

It works fine with Intel's Fortran compiler, however gfortran gives me a couple of errors, the first one being in the line saying

```
CHARACTER(len=:), allocatable :: input_trim
```

I'm not sure which compiler is 'right' regarding the Fortran standard. Plus I don't know how to achieve what I need in a different way?! I think what I'm doing is more of a workaround anyway. What I need is a character variable containing exactly the filename that was entered with no following spaces.

EDIT: The error is "Syntax error in CHARACTER declaration".
gfortran --version gives me "GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)"

EDIT 2: You're right regarding the allocate: With ifort, I don't need it. And gfortran crashes before that so maybe it doesn't need the allocate either but I cannot test this at the moment...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This

```
character (len=:), allocatable :: input_trim
```

is certainly syntactically correct in Fortran 2003. You don't say what the error that `gfortran` raises is, so I can't comment on why it doesn't accept the line -- perhaps you have an old version of the compiler installed.

With an up-to-date Fortran compiler (*eg* Intel Fortran v14.xxx) you don't need to allocate the character variable's size prior to assigning to it, you can simply write

```
input_trim = trim(input)
```

Note that

```
read(*,*) input_trim
```

won't work.

Comment: I think it's the gfortran version! When I asked the question, I was in my office where I couldn't update gfortran. At home, with "GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1" the code works fine!

Comment: Wow, this actually works. It seems fortran just entered the 21st century with seamless integration of dynamic (allocatable) strings.

Answer (score 0):

With Absoft Fortran, this compiles (haven't run with it yet):

```
character,dimension(:),allocatable::Line_for_IO !Metcalf,Reid,Cohen p. 107, w/mods
if(allocated(Line_for_IO)) deallocate(Line_for_IO)
allocate(Line_for_IO(7*n+40))
```

Comment: That code fragment may compile (I don't see why it shouldn't), but it's not clear to me why this is relevant to the question. The question is about deferred length character variables and this answer isn't.  Could you explain further?